# Angular testing example components fail to load templates in karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I'm running the Banner-Spec.testing take it from [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#waiting-compile-components).
While running `npm test` got this error:

```
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.11.6): Executed 0 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 57.0.2987 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) BannerComponent (templateUrl) no title in the DOM until manually call `detectChanges` FAILED
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load app/banner.component.html
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load app/banner.component.html
Error: This test module uses the component BannerComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/app/banner.component.html
ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Failed to load app/banner.component.html', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', 'Failed to load app/banner.component.html', undefined
```

This is my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "angular-io-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "scripts": {
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:upgrade": "tsc",
    "serve:upgrade": "http-server",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "serve:aot": "lite-server -c bs-config.aot.json",
    "build:babel": "babel src -d src --extensions \".es6\" --source-maps",
    "copy-dist-files": "node ./copy-dist-files.js",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.16",
    "@types/angular-animate": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/angular-cookies": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/angular-resource": "^1.5.6",
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.2",
    "@types/angular-sanitize": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-angular2": "^0.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rollup": "^0.36.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^4.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.3.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

My **banner.component.spec.ts**:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';

import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';

describe('BannerComponent (templateUrl)', () => {

  let comp:    BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;

  // async beforeEach
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BannerComponent ], // declare the test component
    })
    .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
  }));

  // synchronous beforeEach
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

    // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  });

  it('no title in the DOM until manually call `detectChanges`', () => {
    expect(el.textContent).toEqual('');
  });

  it('should display original title', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
  });

  it('should display a different test title', () => {
    comp.title = 'Test Title';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.textContent).toContain('Test Title');
  });

});
```

My **banner.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  //moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['./banner.component.css']
})
export class BannerComponent {
  title = 'Test Tour of Heroes';
}
```

This is weird because I took the code from the page and is not working. If I tried to run the app as `npm start` get a `Cannot GET /` message. Also check with the [live example](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview&show=app%2Fbanner.component.spec.ts) and all my files seem to be the same. With another project got the same error message.

I tried suggestions from here and from github's packages pages but couldn't find an answer.

My guess would be with packages versions.

**Edited**: with the correct files names

Comment: when are you getting this error ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to call `fixture.detectChanges()`. Not sure what the reason is for the other errors (failed to load banner.component)

Comment: Add `BannerComponent` html source with question

Comment: @Aravin, when I run `npm test`. @Babar_Bilial, was added but with another file name, I fixed that in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem appeared while following the [Angular Testing guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html), using the quickstart setup. The Angular CLI approach probably wouldn't suffer from the same problem due to webpack inlining the styles and templates.

It appears to be due to a out of date `systemjs-angular-loader.js` in the `quickstart` repository.

If you use take the [version from the `angular.io` repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/21bd32f736e3fe5045776e8cecb1d4190206f7e1/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/src/systemjs-angular-loader.js), you can see it was fixed to work with karma a few days ago. [See this commit.](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/commit/21bd32f736e3fe5045776e8cecb1d4190206f7e1)

Specifically, it seems like the fix is replacing

```
basePath = basePath.replace(baseHref, '');
```

with

```
if (!baseHref.startsWith('/base/')) { // it is not karma
    basePath = basePath.replace(baseHref, '');
}
```

[The changelog entry](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html) *"Component relative paths" cookbook deleted (2017-03-13)*  which describes these changes specifically recommends against using `module: module.id` – this should no longer be necessary.

Comment: That made the trick. Need to add `moduleId: module.id` to my component.

Comment: You shouldn't need it actually, see the latest notes in the changelog: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html "All mention of moduleId removed. "Component relative paths" cookbook deleted (2017-03-13)"

Answer (score 3):

I ended up just overriding the component with the reference (styleUrls in my case), like so:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ BannerComponent ], // declare the test component
})
.overrideComponent(BannerComponent, {
  set: {
    styleUrls: []
    // I assume you can do the same for templateUrl here
  }
})
.compileComponents();  // compile template and css
```